# How to adjust same height as width of any of column class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to apply the same `height` to a `div` as its width applied by column class in bootstrap.

Suppose I have this code.
***Please run this snippet and view in full page mode.***

```css
.item{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to apply the same height as the width.
For example `col-lg-4` is applied and `item` div has `200px` of width. How can I apply the same `200px` height to `item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.item:after{
     display:block;
     content:" ";
     padding-top:100%;
}
```

item:after pseudoelement will take same height as width of it parent (.item)
so '.item' will take same height as its width

Answer (score 1):

equalizer.js is able to make the hight of specific columns the same.